# Microsoft Access Merging Two Excel Files With A SQL Query In Access

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have two simple excel files with both files containing row 1 as the columns. 
FirstName, LastName, Age.

Im trying to merge these files with this SQL Query

SELECT * FROM Sheet1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Sheet2
UNION ALL

ACCESS throws an error saying incomplete or I get an error saying FROM error.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From Access you can select the data from Excel file using query like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [Sheet1] 
    IN "C:\Path\File.xls" [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0]
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM [Sheet2] 
    IN "C:\Path\File.xls" [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0];
```

If Sheet1 and Sheet2 are linked tables, then SQL should be:

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1]
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [Sheet2]
```

Quantity of columns with headers on both sheets should be the same.

Comment: Thank you! When I type Desktop/Sheet1.xls I get an error for Path Invalid?

Comment: You should use full path, starting drive letter. Shortcuts like "Desktop" won't work

Comment: I put it in my documents. Can you give me an example of a path? Im still having errors

Comment: Example of path to file in Documents folder: `C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Sheet1.xls`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have *linked* the worksheets. If not, do that and reduce your query:

```
SELECT * FROM Sheet1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Sheet2
```

where Sheet1 and Sheet2 are the names of the linked tables.